# How to interpret a scaled response variable as an unscaled response variable?

Tags: regression, units, scaled

I'm new to R and I'm having trouble to interpret the estimates of my scaled response variable.

I used `(scale)` function to standardize all my variables (1 response variable and 7 explanatory variables) in a `lmer`model. The estimates (in  `summary`) of my non-scaled model response variable were in minutes, but now I don't know how to interpret them. If I know how much 1 SD is in minutes, I can calculate my estimates in minutes again, but how do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the standard deviations of your features. Then you can interpret the coefficients.

For instance, let a variable of interest have a standard deviation of $2$, and let its regression coefficient for the scales variable be $3$. Also, let’s scale $y$, which has an unscaled standard deviation of $6$. The interpretation is that, for a one-SD change in the variable, we expect a change of $3$ standard deviations in $y$. Converting back to the original scales, for a one-unit change in the variable, we expect a change of $6*2/3=4$ in $y$.